# Simple objective-c code segfaulting with NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions

Tags: objective-c, segmentation-fault, exc-bad-access

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AppKit/AppKit.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{     
@autoreleasepool {

    NSArray* windowList = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    windowList = [NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions:0];
    NSLog(@"%lu", [windowList count]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Segfaulting when calling NSWindow windowNumbersWithOptions

Comment: Show the backtrace of the segfault.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/2968987

Comment: Crashing down in CG code called by AppKit is almost assuredly a bug. You should file a report with Apple.

Comment: You can call this from inside a Cocoa application's delegate method -applicationDidFinishLaunching:, but not in main().  I would guess that the CG calls need a little more setup before you can make this NSWindow call.

Answer (score 1):

The doc for `windowNumbersWithOptions` says, for the option value,

> If the value 0 is passed instead, then the list returned from the method contains window numbers for visible windows on the active space belonging to the calling application.

Probably your `windowList` is `NULL`, because your app didn't create one?